# Excel: check if comma separated list in a cell contains a sub-substring instead of a substring

Tags: excel, dataset

So, 
I'm trying to create my own dataset. I've got all data from a website and store them into a Excel spreadsheet. 
Now, for every attribute, I want to say if a cell has a specific value in it with a **0** (not contained) or a **1** (contained).

I looked at the tutorial given [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/check-if-a-cell-contains-text-case-insensitive-7bb505c7-2815-4a7a-9544-57a5f0dcd551) but this method doesn't fit well with my problem. I used the function written like so:

*=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Violence", C3)), 1, 0)*

As shown in the image below, I wanted to say if a game has a *"Violence"* as *Descriptors*. 
For the first game everything is ok, but for the second one it's not.
That happend just because the function searches for "*Violence*" and the second game has "Fantasy *Violence*" in it. 
Then, when I try to check *"Fantasy Violence"*, everything is ok.

So i thought about using the **XOR** function but it can happen that a game may contain both attributes. So it's no longer a choice...

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

How can I avoid this behavior? What should I do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you expect for output for 2nd game?

Comment: 0 for "Violence" and 1 for "Fantasy Violence"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my result is in "**E2**" cell

=SUM(IF(E$1=TRIM(TEXTSPLIT($C2,,",")),1,0))

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

```
D2: =--OR(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT($C2,","))=D$1)
```

and fill down and across

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use wildcards like so:

[image]

So shown find() and countif() - you can test for other functions.

Comment: How can I implements those inside my function?

Comment: Well, replace the search(). Or try adding the wildcards to the search() - see what happens. You learn by trying.